# How do I make a button handle it's on OnClick event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been creating several custom controls in ASP.NET - mostly for practice and a deeper understanding of the language.

I've been fiddling with a button but I can't seem to get it to handle its own OnClick event.  Can anyone help me out?

```
public class CustomButton : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
{
    private string href = "";

    public CustomButton(string name = "Custom Button", string link = "~/errors/404.aspx", string css = "custom_button")
    {
        this.Text = name;
        this.href = link;
        this.CssClass = css;
        //this.OnClick += redirect;
        this.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "redirect");
    }
    protected void redirect(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I want this function to redirect the user to another page.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the OnClick method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick.aspx

> The OnClick method also allows derived classes to handle the event
>   without attaching a delegate. This is the preferred technique for
>   handling the event in a derived class.

Comment: Thanks!  That's much simpler than I thought it was going to be.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.OnClick+= redirect(sender,e);
```

Try that?

Comment: For derived classes is better to override the OnClick method.

Comment: Ah, did not know that. Thanks for pointing that out. Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call to a javascript function you might want to try this:

```
this.OnClientClick = "Function()";
```